# python tabulate tablefmt=rounded_outline prints 3 spaces instead of 1 space between columns

Tags: python, tabulate

How can i avoid extra spaces in the tabulate grid?

```
rows = [
    ["A1", "B2"],
    ["C3", "D4"],
    ["E5", "E6"],
]
print(tabulate(rows, headers="firstrow", tablefmt='rounded_outline'))
```

gives me 2 extra spaces in every cell

```
╭──────┬──────╮
│ A1   │ B2   │
├──────┼──────┤
│ C3   │ D4   │
│ E5   │ E6   │
╰──────┴──────╯
```

how can i solve it to get

```
╭────┬────╮
│ A1 │ B2 │
├────┼────┤
│ C3 │ D4 │
│ E5 │ E6 │
╰────┴────╯
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the `MIN_PADDING` constant.

```py
import tabulate

rows = [
    ["A1", "B2"],
    ["C3", "D4"],
    ["E5", "E6"],
]

tabulate.MIN_PADDING = 0

print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="rounded_outline"))
```

Outputs:

```
╭────┬────╮
│ A1 │ B2 │
├────┼────┤
│ C3 │ D4 │
│ E5 │ E6 │
╰────┴────╯
```

Comment: wow, works great :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a global [minimum padding](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/blob/95ae5eb61ef969749e904c90ab429003238d6212/tabulate/__init__.py#L33) setting you can change. I don't know how recommended that is but they mention it for the whitespace handling.

```py
import tabulate
tabulate.MIN_PADDING = 0
rows = [
    ["A1", "B2"],
    ["C3", "D4"],
    ["E5", "E6"],
]
print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, headers="firstrow", tablefmt='rounded_outline'))
```